# Dark Mode inconsistencies in Windows 10 / 11 UI

Tags: windows, themes, user-interface, dark-mode

Dark Mode settings in Windows 10 (and Windows 11) are only partially implemented and inconsistent, which is odd, and sometimes jarring (when you are in File Explorer and then open up a Properties window and it's super bright). e.g.
[image]

I came across this discussion from 2 years ago, and while some of the points were interesting, it devolves into criticising Microsoft's strategy in general. https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/mys49h/can_we_get_a_dark_mode_file_explorer_properties/

That aside, and as this was 2 years ago, I'm really curious if anyone here knows of a way to make the *whole* UI go into Dark Mode (and, for example, make Properties windows like the above operate in Dark Mode also)?

Comment: It is work in progress.  Right now, Microsoft is enforcing unreadable dark mode Task Manager in light mode Windows.  I think they may be working on this.

Comment: I've not seen dark mode Task Manager on Windows 10 or Windows 11 ... you are seeing this in the Insider Ring? I don't bother going into the Insider Ring on my main system, but that's pretty interesting if so.

Comment: Windows 22H2 Production now only has Dark Mode Task Manager - unreadable and not fixable at this point.

Comment: Please see this for additional information. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/task-manager-lightdark-mode-bug/8c8420dd-5a70-4bb7-9dab-a6a812a82a1f